How to send a user notification in C# on MacOS
I'm writing an Avalonia application (which currently does not have any way of sending OS specific notifications), and I want to send a push notification (user notification on MacOS) in the application. The only way to do this, as far as I've found, seems to be Xamarin. However, this ended support in May 2024 and Microsoft has not given any proper alternative. Even their website gives incorrect information about what to do. MAUI does not work as far as I've tried (it does not include the UserNotifications library, which is needed). So if anyone could help me with this, I'd greatly appreciate it.
